# PHPAGI / Cepstral / Asterisk - License Issue

Tags: asterisk

I am writing an IVR script for Asterisk in PHPAGI and trying to use Cepstral for TTS.  Though I have licensed the product, when I call $agi->swift(), before my text is "read" (during a call), the engine / voice states that the product isn't licensed.  Has anyone else encountered this and know of the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to recompile the TTS with the licensed voice. Or just try to replace audio files with the registered one.
 If still the problem persist you can consult with the cepestral support as you have the license of their product so you have all right to keep their support engineer busy until & unless your box is up and running as desired :)

Comment: Thanks.  You were right, though I did not understand what you were referring to initially, I did find that there was some caching happening with the rendered audio files. But also, after speaking with Cepstral support, it was found that there is a difference in licensing between the licenses sold through Digium vs those direct from Cepstral, there is a limitation from where you can call the engine.  So I ended up purchasing another license (direct this time) which allowed me to call it from within the AGI script.